# vlc failed play rtsp video from command line

Tags: command-line, video, vlc

I am using Ubuntu and VLC for an application which needs a tiled-of 5X4 videos in the screen. The video source are ip Cameras and it transmit videos as RTSP streams. the sample URL to access the feed is  `rtsp://192.168.1.7:554/user=admin&password=&channel=1&stream=1.sdp?real_stream--rtp-caching=100` The link mentioned above will open directly from the vlc media player, but when it comes to the command line it failed to open. The command i tried is

```
cvlc rtsp://192.168.1.7:554/user=admin&password=&channel=1&stream=1.sdp?real_stream--rtp-caching=100
```

I am neither getting error nor getting warning it is an absolute idle state. When I hit enter it return back to the command prompt.

Kindly help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the / to a ? works for me, but I have no idea why

cvlc rtsp://192.168.2.33:554?user=admin&password=&channel=2&stream=1.sdp?real_stream--rtp-caching=100

you might also try

cvlc rtsp://192.168.2.33:554/?user=admin&password=&channel=2&stream=1.sdp?real_stream--rtp-caching=100

Comment: Still its not working... Let me try in some other manner and let you know

Answer (score 0):

cvlc "rtsp://192.168.1.7:554/user=admin&password=&channel=1&stream=1.sdp?real_stream"

it worked for me. Just put the url to inside ""